# Cinnamon Settings Panel Blank After v 2.0.6

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

After cinnamon upgrade to 2.0.6-20131026040307-precise via synaptic, the "cinnamon settings" gui or window is broken.  It appears blank, only showing the configuration category icons for "Appearance", "Preferences", "Hardware", and "Administration".  The icons that should be within these categories are gone.  I don't know if cinnamon-control-center was removed during the last cinnamon update, but this issue began on Oct. 25.

When running cinnamon-settings from terminal, several errors appear such as this:

```
Could not load screen module; is the cinnamon-control-center package installed?
/usr/lib/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_user.py:112: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
file_icon = Gio.FileIcon().new(file)

(cinnamon-settings.py:5471): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkMenuItem, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkMenuItem can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkAccelLabel

Could not find network module; is the cinnamon-control-center package installed?
```

cinnamon-control-center is not installed in synaptic, and when the module is marked for installation, unity is selected for removal.  Is there any way to get this function back without removing unity?

Release: Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)

Kernel: 3.2.0-55-generic

Desktop: Cinnamon 2.0.6-20131026040307-precise

Some settings are still accessible through terminal by appending  the name of the function to the command:

```
cinnamon-settings panel
cinnamon-settings calendar
cinnamon-settings themes
cinnamon-settings applets
cinnamon-settings windows
cinnamon-settings fonts
cinnamon-settings hotcorner
```

Comment: Seems that this is a bug in cinnamon. A search conducting to several post which solutions was rather hacky and ended in bug reports.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to solve the issue, this fix has been confirmed to work on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and 32-bit:

1. List item
2. Open a terminal
3. Issue the following command: sudo gedit /usr/lib/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py
4. Enter your password
5. Gedit will open with elevated privileges. Go to line 325 (lines can be seen at the bottom of Gedit).
6. Press enter and in the newly created line add the following: widget.set_item_width(105)
7. Save and close.

This should do it for now. 
The solution was highlighted by Bob Wanamaker pointing to a GitHub commit as follows: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/commit/c4eac2e3ab88a2264faedf09f026432522bbe18e

NOTE: Use this fix at your own risk. Always make a copy of the original file, in case things go wrong.